# c# creating a generic FLAT serialisable model

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how I can serialise some data into this generic format (Array of dynamic objects)

```
[
 {
    Character: "BreakTooth",
    Aggression: "High",
    Strength: 50,
 },
 {
    Character: "SandyPants",
    Aggression: "Low",
    Strength: 70,
 },
 {
    Character: "BlueCrack",
    Aggression: "High",
    Strength: 90,
 }
]
```

Where my original dataset would be like this:

```
Character  | Quality    | Value
===============================
BreakTooth | Aggression | High
BreakTooth | Strength   | 50
SandyPants | Aggression | Low
SandyPants | Strength   | 70
BlueCrack  | Aggression | High
BlueCrack  | Strength   | 90
```

This dataset could be a list of:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Character { get;set; }
    public string Quality { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

or it could be a datatable of the same three fields.

The issue here is that this table is, of course, dynamic - where there can be **more than two qualities and respective values** associated with each character. I have no way of knowing how many `Qualities` there will be but they will always be the same for each `Character` in any query.

This is really two tables joined together, and I do have the ability to create this architecture if needed. So I could also create separate models like:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Character { get; set; }
    public List<Quality> Qualities { get; set; }
}

public class Quality
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking to use anonymous selections on the original model e.g.

```
var result = ds.select(x => new { Character = x.Character, x.Quality.ToString() = x.Value });
```

where `ds` is an IEnumerable of the model with three properties `Character` `Quality` `Value`

but I can't assign the property name dynamically like using `x.Quality.ToString()` and I'm not even sure that'd work since it'd need another iteration of the dynamic properties inside.

Is it possible to achieve this? Even if I create separated models the issue is ***How do I flatten the inner qualities to get a simple list of new anonymous model?***

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Dictionary for this

```
public class Model
{
    public string Character { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Qualities { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
Model model = new Model
{
    Character = "Super Foo",
    Qualities = new Dictionary<string, string> 
    {
        { "Strength", "100" },
        { "Aggression", "Low" }
    }
}
```

Then access the qualities using:

```
string agression = model.Qualities["Aggression"];
```

This should then serialize and deserialize ok.

Comment: I tried similar with keyvaluepairs, I'm not sure how to serialise that into the required format though, I need to "flatten" it so the dictionary entries are at the same level as the `Character` property

Answer (score 0):

Different answer.

If you can, I would just use a defined model that you know will serialize to the correct json and back.

```
public class Model
{
    public string Character { get;set; }
    public string Aggression { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    ...etc.
}
```

This may not fit if you truly have an arbitrary list of potential qualities, but if you actually have a specific, defined set of qualities then this is best because you'll be able to have each quality a different type (int, string, etc.) and you'll be able to write meaningful code for any logic linked with them.

I think it would be the job of a service or repository class to then generate the model by getting the list of the character's qualities from the table and populating the related properties.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way I could predict what the models will be, they could literally be in their thousands. I think I'll just have to write some iterative logic and it's going to end up super slow :s